# What's the solution to "CreateFontPackage failed: Win32 error:1035"?

Tags: winforms, fonts, rdlc

Trying to use the **Libre Baskerville** font in an RDLC but it causes an error on rendering:

> CreateFontPackage failed: Win32 error:1035

There's little information online about this error (none of Google's results suggest any solutions) ... is there anything we can do about it other than switch to a more conventional font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that error 1035 stands for the "The font did not contain a loca table." error.

The 'loca' table is a part of a font definition. You can see detailed description [here](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=IWS-Chapter08).

It seems that your font file is damaged. Try to download the font from another source or switch to another font.

Answer (score 2):

I know this problem is a bit old, but right now I faced the same problem with "Helvetica-Neue" font, which is the corporate font for publications.  I am building my reports with ReportBuilder 2.0 (SqlServer 2008).

Diagnostics:

I used the Microsoft Font Validator to check whether the font is "well-formed", here I could find that the original font (OTF by the way) could not be rastered due to missing tables.

Solution:

I decided to convert the OTF file into TTF (I googled for an online converter) then ran the test over the new TTF file for the same font, and everything was OK.

I went to the control panel to remove all the styles of the "Helvetica-Neue" font (I had about 50).

Installed the TTF I got from the conversion, and my problems were solved, the report was able to be exported to PDF without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information related to this issue ..
Mainly

```
 error:1035
```

1>
Am not sure if this will help but try removing the `Datasource` from the Report menu and then adding it again.

2>
created a new RDLC file for your report page.Try again .